# Help understanding command line

Tags: bash

We are starting our Jenkins CI with the following bash command that I would like understand. Could someone explain what is doing (the only bit I get is "java -jar jenkins.war"). Thanks!

```
nohup java -jar jenkins.war > $HOME/jenkins.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `nohup` means it will continue to run when you exit the shell.

The `>` means redirect the standard output to a file

The file it is being redirected to is `$HOME/jenkins.log`. You can find the value of `$HOME` by running `echo $HOME`

`2>&1` means redirect standard errors to standard output, so in this example will also go into `$HOME/jenkins.log`.

The `< /dev/null` means read data in from `/dev/null`. So if the script is expecting input it will read that instead of waiting for user input.

And the `&` means run as a background task, and return you to the command line.

If you want more detail, ask in the comments.

Comment: you was too quick for me :+

Comment: For me, too as it seems :-D

Comment: This question has links to some documentation you can use to learn a bit more about the command line. http://askubuntu.com/questions/85709/what-do-these-symbols-in-some-linux-terminal-commands-mean

Comment: Rinzwind, Michael K: Yes but at the expense of poorly formatted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
nohup
```

detaches the following command from the current terminal session, which prevents the process from being closed on terminal exit.

```
java
```

then runs the java VM with the options

```
-jar jenkins.war
```

which tells java to run the main class from the jar-archive jenkins.war

```
>
```

forwards the standard output (what usually appears in the terminal) into the given file, in this case into `$HOME/jenkins.log`

```
2>&1
```

means that the optput of the error channel is connected to the output of the standard output channel.

```
< /dev/null
```

sends "nothing" as input stream to the java command.

Finally & forces the task into backgrount such that the control returns to the prompt.

Comment: Actually, `/dev/null` is *not* the input stream consisting of zeroes (that's `/dev/zero`), it is an input stream that has null content.  In other words, if the java process tries to read something from the standard input, it will immediately read end-of-file.

Comment: You re right, corrected it.